# Can recurrent dropout be used as a Bayesian approximation?

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, dropout

To express model uncertainty in LSTM, we can use dropout as a Bayesian approximation for Gaussian model according to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02142.pdf), (dropout is kept during inference and that will result in a distribution of prediction based on my understanding).

My question, does this apply to recurrent dropout as well, proposed [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.05118.pdf)? The dashed line in the below figure illustrates the recurrent dropout I am talking about, which was proposed in the mentioned paper.

[image]

Comment: I'm just here to comment that MC dropout has its limitations https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrew-Foong-2/publication/335599363_Pathologies_of_Factorised_Gaussian_and_MC_Dropout_Posteriors_in_Bayesian_Neural_Networks/links/5dcd9ad392851c382f3dea56/Pathologies-of-Factorised-Gaussian-and-MC-Dropout-Posteriors-in-Bayesian-Neural-Networks.pdf